# How to load data to form with ajax

Tags: php

i have problem about ajax load,,when i input the name or id to form seacrh ,cannot work,
i have looking for solve this problem but until now i cannot solve it, please the answer,thanks

this my source code

```
<?php
include("../configurasi/koneksi.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="modulpembelian/pem.js"></script>


</head>
    <body>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Customer Activity</h1>

            <script>

                $(function ()
                {
                    $("#wizard").steps({
                        headerTag: "h2",
                        bodyTag: "section",
                        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
                          onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {

            alert("Submitted!");
            window.location.href='../sipp2/content.php?module=pembelian';
        }
                    });


                });
            </script>

            <div id="wizard">
                <h2>Cari Data Pembeli</h2>
                <section>

 <div id="divSearch">
  <form id="formSearch">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Cari Berdasarkan</td><td><select id="pilihcari">
      <option value="namapembeli">Nama Pembeli</option>
      <option value="kodepembeli">Kode Pembeli</option>
      <option value="semua">Semua</option>
  </select></td>
  <td id="kolompilih"><input type="text" name="fieldcari" id="fieldcari" /></td><td>
  <input type="submit" value="Cari" /></td>
  </tr></table>
  </form><br />
</div>
<div id="divPageData"></div>

                </section>

                <h2>Transaksi</h2>
                <section>

                </section>

                <h2>Input Cicilan</h2>
                <section>

                </section>

                <h2>Selesai</h2>
                <section>
                    checking dan liat data2 nya lagi
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
//menangkap error dan men-set parameter global (timeout, dll)
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 10000,
    cache: false,
    error:function(x,e){
        if(x.status==0){
            alert('Anda sedang offline!\nSilahkan cek koneksi anda!');
        }else if(x.status==404){
            alert('Permintaan URL tidak ditemukan!');
        }else if(x.status==500){
            alert('Internal Server Error!');
        }else if(e=='parsererror'){
            alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed!');
        }else if(e=='timeout'){
            alert('Request Time out!');
        }else {
            alert('Error tidak diketahui: \n'+x.responseText);
        }
    }
});


//menangani jika user melakukan pilihan pada combo #pilihcari
$("select#pilihcari").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "kodepembeli"){
        $("td#kolompilih").show();
        $("input#fieldcari").show();
        $("input#fieldcari").focus();
    }
    else if ($(this).val() == "namapembeli"){
        $("td#kolompilih").show();
        $("input#fieldcari").show();
        $("input#fieldcari").focus();
    }

    else{
        $("td#kolompilih").hide();
    }
});

//menampilkan list data pelanggan
loadData();

// fungsi untuk me-load tampilan list data pelanggan, data yang ditampilkan disesuaikan
// juga dengan input data pada bagian search
function loadData(){
    var dataString;
    var cari = $("input#fieldcari").val();
    var combo = $("select#pilihcari").val();

    if (combo == "namapembeli"){
        dataString = 'namapembeli='+ cari;
    }
    else if (combo == "kodepembeli"){
        dataString = 'kodepembeli='+ cari;
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: "modulpembelian/search.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: dataString,
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#divPageData').html(data);
        }
    });
}

// melakukan pemrosesan data untuk bagian search (pencarian data)
$("form#formSearch").submit(function()
{
    var cari = $("input#fieldcari").val();
    var combo = $("select#pilihcari").val();
    if (cari.replace(/\s/g,"") != ""){ // mengecek field text kosong atau tidak)
        loadData();
    }
    else if ((cari.replace(/\s/g,"") == "") && (combo != "semua") ){
        alert("Maaf, field nya harus diisi!");
        $("input#fieldcari").focus();
    }
    else{
        loadData();
    }
    return false;
});
```

});

```
<?php
include("../configurasi/koneksi.php");
?>
  <script type="text/javascript">

// fungsi ini untuk menampilkan list data pelanggan sesuai halaman (page) yang dipilih.
// list data yang ditampilkan disesuaikan juga dengan input data pada bagian search.
function pagination(page)
{
  var cari = $("input#fieldcari").val();
  var combo = $("select#pilihcari").val();

  if (combo == "namapembeli"){
    dataString = 'namapembeli='+cari;
  }
  else (combo == "kodepembeli"){
    dataString = 'kodepembeli='+cari;
  }


  $.ajax({
    url:"modulpembelian/search.php",
    data: dataString,
    type:"GET",
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#divPageData').html(data);
    }
  });
}

// fungsi untuk me-load tampilan list data pelanggan, data yang ditampilkan disesuaikan
// juga dengan input data pada bagian search
function loadData(){
  var dataString;
  var cari = $("input#fieldcari").val();
  var combo = $("select#pilihcari").val();

  if (combo == "namapembeli"){
    dataString = 'namapembeli='+ cari;
  }
  else if (combo == "kodepembeli"){
    dataString = 'kodepembeli='+ cari;
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "modulpembelian/search.php", //file tempat pemrosesan permintaan (request)
    type: "GET",
    data: dataString,
    success:function(data)
    {
      $('#divPageData').html(data);
    }
  });
}

$(function(){
  // membuat warna tampilan baris data pada tabel menjadi selang-seling
  $('#data/stock_barang tr:even:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('even');
  $('#data/stock_barang tr:odd:not(#nav):not(#total)').addClass('odd');

  $("a.edit").click(function(){
    page=$(this).attr("href");
    $("#divFormContent").load(page); // me-load formpelanggan untuk melakukan edit data
    $("#divFormContent").show();
    $("#btnhide").show();
    return false;
  });


});

</script>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['namapembeli']) and !empty($_GET['namapembeli'])){
  $nama = $_GET['namapembeli'];
  $sql = "select * from datapembeli where namapelanggan like '%$nama%'";
}

?>
       <table>
<tr>
<td><font color="red">ID Pembeli</font></td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $data[idpembeli]; ?>" name=""/><td>
<td><font color="red">Nama Pembeli</font></td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td><font color="red">No KTP</font></td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>R</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Ca</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>L</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>No telepon</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Usia</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Alamat</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Jenis Kelamin</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Tanggal Lahir</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Agama</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Jumlah Keluarga</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Pendidikan</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Pekerjaan</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Penghasilan</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Penghasilan Lain</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Pekerjaan</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Email</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>Nip</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
<td>No kartu Pegawai</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" value="" name=""/><td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal version that holds code (or snippets) of the relevant parts? Please state as well what you tried already to a) find out what exactly the problem is and b) what you tried to solve it.

Comment: the main of my topic is how i can get data from database
when i input on the "textbox" and then the data show to form below 

may be you can show me the example so i can explore more

Comment: Please tell exactly what is not working.

Comment: i cannot load data when i click button search,the right is when i put text in text area and then i click button,example the name is "John" and then after that will be show the data of john in "form".my be you have the sample like that,or may be show the incorrect my code,thanks my friend

Comment: this is my picture,sorry i cannot show in this thread,because after ten post,i can post the image
http://i1112.photobucket.com/albums/k491/kujil/tes1_zpsa9d92321.jpg